# How to add pgadmin db in program.cs in asp.net mvc core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, pgadmin-4

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DEM_MASTERSContext>(options =>        options.UseSQLserver(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")));

how to add connection string for pgadmin 4 , above one is for sqlserver

Comment: what do you mean connection string for pgadmin4, pgadmin4 is not a database, it is tool to manage postgres database. do you mean connection string for postgres database ?

Answer (score 1):

for postgres you can add like this

```
services.AddDbContext<PostgreSqlContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")));
```

For more you can follow [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-postgresql-with-ef-core-and-asp-net-core-web-api/) or [this](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/06/23/net-6-connect-to-postgresql-database-with-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 1):

`pgadmin4` is not a database, Do you want to ask how to connect to PostgreSQL?

First, you need to add NuGet package:

```
dotnet add package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

Then, you need to add `connectionstring` in `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "WebApiDatabase": "Host=localhost; Database=xxx; Username=xxx; Password=xxx"
    },
}
```

Finally configure it like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<xxxContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings")));
```

Answer (score 0):

for Program.cs like this

```
builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(opt =>
        opt.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SampleDbConnection")));
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**